# Convert Pandas Dataframe to dbf file

Tags: python, pandas, dbf

I need to change the datatype or a database file from float to integer. I thought converting the `dbf` into a `Dataframe` then converting back to a `dbf` would be the most straight forward way. What would be the fastest way to convert  a `dataframe` into a `dfb`?

Comment: Is this DBF file a component of a shapefile?

Comment: @PaulH no, it is a stand alone dbf file